# Constant update of the form's data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, capslock, num-lock

This is basically a simple question.

I want to update the label dynamically when I press the <kbd>capslock</kbd> and <kbd>numlock</kbd> keys while the main form is open in the WinForm application on the `.net` platform. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683620/c-sharp-actively-detect-lock-keys  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577411/how-can-i-find-the-state-of-numlock-capslock-and-scrolllock-in-net

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen for keypress callbacks like that

```
private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        Keys k = (Keys)Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        if (k == Keys.Capital)
        {
            label1.Text = "Heureka";
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```